# Recursion output isn't printing

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new to python and trying to understand recursion. I'm trying to write a code where someone inputs 2 numbers (Num1, Num2). A calculation will take place until Num1 is greater than Num 2. The result of the calculation's final value should then be outputted.

This is my code:

```
def Recursive(Num1, Num2):
    if Num1 > Num2:
        return(10)
    else:
        if Num1 == Num2:
            return(Num1)
        else:
            return(Num1+Recursive(Num1 * 2, Num2))

Num1=input("Enter number 1: ")
Num2=input("Enter number 2: ")
print("Final value: ", Recursive(Num1, Num2))
```

This is the output that comes out:

```
Enter number 1: 1
Enter number 2: 15
```

That's it. There's no output of my print statement. I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong here and what I should do.

Comment: What is `Result`?

Comment: My bad, I was trying something different hoping it would work (which it didn't) but forgot to change it back to the original code before copying it. Fixed it now.

Comment: Just a typo. You meant to write: `Num1=int(input("Enter number 1: "))` etc

Comment: Ahh I was so focused on the function - thinking it was that which was causing the error - that I missed this completely. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def Recursive(Num1, Num2):
    if Num1 > Num2:
        return 10
    if Num1 == Num2:
        return Num1
    print(Num1, Num2)
    return Num1 + Recursive(Num1 * 2, Num2)

Num1=int(input("Enter number 1: "))
Num2=int(input("Enter number 2: "))
print("Final value: ", Recursive(Num1, Num2))
```

This should be working code, the reason why your code was not working was because without the `int` in `Num1 = int( input("") )` the program was reading the number as a string. As a result instead of getting `2` from `Num1 * 2` when `Num1` is `1` you got `11` as it was multiplying a string instead of an integer.

```
# Here is an example

a = input("Input a number: ")
b = int(input("input a number: "))

print(f"a is a:{type(a)}\n b is a:{type(b)}")

print(f"{a * 2}\n{b * 2}")
```

Copy the code above input the two numbers and it should give you a better understanding of what I just said.